# Informix DB; query output, forcing table output?

Tags: database, output, informix, aix

All..

I am currently using some systems that has an Informix DB on some older IBM AIX OS based systems.  I have found myself needing to use the command line "dbaccess" feature to make some quick queries.   Informix has this really annoying habit of return output in this format:

```
employee           -1
record_desc        Update
field_id           2 
value           
opr_activity_date  20150831
opr_activity_time  1 

employee           -1
record_desc        Update
field_id           2
value
opr_activity_date  20150831
opr_activity_time  1

employee           -1
record_desc        Update
field_id           2
value
opr_activity_date  20150831
opr_activity_time  1
```

MySQL, MSSQL, etc.. all output something more readable in table format..

```
city            state zipcode
Sunnyvale       CA    94086
San Francisco   CA    94117
Palo Alto       CA    94303
Redwood City    CA    94026
Los Altos       CA    94022
Mountain View   CA    94063
Palo Alto       CA    94304
Redwood City    CA    94063
```

I noticed that Informix will/can output in a column/table format, but I have not figured out any rhyme or reason as to how it decides the flat versus the table format.

Any idea how I can force Informix to always display in column/table output via the command line?

Obviously, this is not an issue when I am near my computer and can use my GUI tool to query the DB...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to control this behaviour in DB-Access.

If the width of the selected columns (plus a little white space) exceeds the width of the terminal, DB-Access switches to that block format, because it doesn't support sideways scrolling. That's the rhyme and reason.

You can try messing around with your terminal settings so that DB-Access is aware on start-up that the terminal width is wider than 80 characters, but I've always found there's more luck than science to that, and you'll still trigger the behaviour on some queries and not others.

When I need to do what you're describing - ad hoc, simple queries for troubleshooting etc - I tend to work within VIM rather than DB-Access, and use a macro to run the query and format the output. (This is using DBI::Shell behind the scenes.) I've also got a program that accepts either a table name or SQL statement and outputs tab-delimited, CSV or an old-school ASCII character formatted table of the results. This is also perl based. I could publish either of these if there's interest in them.

I think Jonathan Leffler's SQLCMD program can also be used in place of DB-Access to generate arbitrarily wide output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the DBACCESS_COLUMNS environment variable. It is supported from version 12.10.xC9.

Example:

```
export DBACCESS_COLUMNS=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok..

While I found the answers RET provided to be correct and pretty much sums up what I have been able to find on the net, I also found some work-arounds that enable the ability to get what you want, but in a kludgy way!  Thanks Informix! :(

Open two terminal windows to your DB system, and launch the dbaccess and authenticate and connect to your database.

Next perform the following:

```
unload to /home/(user)/out  ...the query...
```

Example:

```
unload to /home/jewettg/out  select * from books_checked_in;
```

It will output the query results to the file and return the row-count of the return result.

On the second terminal, and here is the cool thing, run the following command:

```
column -t -s '|' /home/(user)/out
```

This will grab the content of the "out" file, and convert the pipe-delimited content to space-delimit content and output it to the screen.

Like I said, kludgy, but it works!